# Converting Client String to Array on Server C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, tcp

I want to convert the string the server is receiving from the client to in an array. However when I use the String.Split method the result variable is showing null. Anyone know why that might be?

[image: Array is not filled when using <code>split</code>]

```
namespace ExampleLib.Server
{

    public class Server
    {
        private class ConnectedClient
        {
            public int ID { get; }
            private TcpClient _client;
            private StreamReader _streamReader;

            public delegate void NetDataEventHandler(object sender, NetDataEventArgs e);

            public event NetDataEventHandler NetData;

            public virtual void OnNetData(NetDataEventArgs e)
            {
                NetData?.Invoke(this, e);
            }

            public class NetDataEventArgs
            {
                public NetDataEventArgs(int id, string message)
                {
                    ID = id;
                    Message = message;
                }

                public string Message { get; }
                public int ID { get; }
            }
        public ConnectedClient(int id, TcpClient client)
          {
            ID = id;
            _client = client;
           }

    private void ClientReceiveData(object sender, ConnectedClient.NetDataEventArgs e)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message) == false)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine($" Client {e.ID}: {e.Message}");
                    var result = e.Message.Split(',');
                }
            }
```

Comment: `result` shows `null` because that line hasn't executed yet. You haven't finished the assignment to the variable. What happens if you press `F10`?

Comment: Have you stepped forward in your debugger to check if the variable was assigned? Your image is at the step, but `result` won't be assigned until you continue past that step.

Comment: Ya it works my apologies I didn't realize I had the break-point at the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stopped at the break-point.

You should proceed one more step, in order for that line to be executed.

Currently, you're at a step similar to this.

[image]

If you proceed one more step using `F10` (or 'Step Over' button) , it will execute that line and assign the value of addition to `c` in this example.